# Copy value from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, foreach

I have two pairs of elements. First pair is `.original`, which contains child elements with each having specific font-size. The second is `.copy` with no font-size defined within it's child elements.

When a user clicks one of the `.original` elements it should copy the css `font-size` from it's children to the children of the `.copy` element with the same index. For example, if a user clicks first `.original` element the font-size value should be copyied to children of the first `.copy` element.

Currently i can only copy the last font-size value with the loop below.

```js
$('.original').click(function() {
    $(this).find('div').each(function(i) {
      font = $(this).css('font-size');
      len  = $(this).length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        $('.copy div').css('font-size', font)
      }
    })
})
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
.original {
  background: #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.original > div {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.copy {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
.copy > div {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t-1 original">
  <div style="font-size: 14px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 16px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 18px">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="t-2 original">
  <div style="font-size: 20px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 22px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 24px">Test</div>
</div>


<div class="t-1 copy">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
<div class="t-2 copy">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$('.original').click(function() {
    var original_divs = $(this).find('div'),
        index = $(this).index('.original');
    $('.copy').eq(index).find('div').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('font-size', original_divs.eq(i).css('font-size'));
    });
})
```

```css
/* Your original CSS */ div,div>div{display:inline-block}div{width:100%}div>div{content:"";width:30px;height:30px;float:left}.original{background:#bbb;cursor:pointer}.original>div{padding-right:10px}.copy{width:100%;display:block;margin-top:20px;clear:both}.copy>div{font-size:10px}
```

```html
<!-- Your original HTML --> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="t-1 original"> <div style="font-size: 14px">Test</div><div style="font-size: 16px">Test</div><div style="font-size: 18px">Test</div></div><div class="t-2 original"> <div style="font-size: 20px">Test</div><div style="font-size: 22px">Test</div><div style="font-size: 24px">Test</div></div><div class="t-1 copy"> <div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div></div><div class="t-2 copy"> <div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try like this**

```js
$('.original').click(function() {
    $('.'+$(this).data('target')).html($(this).html());
})
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
.original {
  background: #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.original > div {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.copy {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
.copy > div {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t-1 original" data-target="t-1-paste">
  <div style="font-size: 14px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 16px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 18px">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="t-2 original" data-target="t-2-paste">
  <div style="font-size: 20px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 22px">Test</div>
  <div style="font-size: 24px">Test</div>
</div>


<div class="t-1-paste">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
<div class="t-2-paste">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

> Note: Added `data-target` attribute for paste target.

Comment: Yes i know but my data/test might change so i need to copy only css values.

Comment: Ahh! I see! Ok (y) @g5wx